# Is it possible to use new Blob(array,options) to create a blob if we have a local filepath?

Tags: javascript, filepath, filereader, data-uri

Such as

```
wx.chooseImage({
  count: 1,
  sizeType: ['compressed'],
  sourceType: ['camera'],
  success: (res)=>{
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = ()=>{
      that.setData({
        selfie: reader.result
      })
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([res.tempFilePaths[0].slice(2)],{type:'image/jpeg'}))
  }
})
```

Let's say `res.tempFilePaths[0] = wxfile://tmp_182046745o6zAJsz3uqHiNpvw66iUfDIjvPTkb31ab4e0f79bac5f21063348326464a8.jpg`

Sadly this outputs:

`ZmlsZTovL3RtcF8xODIwNDY3NDVvNnpBSnN6M3VxSGlOcHZ3NjZpVWZESWp2UFRrYjMxYWI0ZTBmNzliYWM1ZjIxMDYzMzQ4MzI2NDY0YTguanBn`

Which decodes to...`file://tmp_182046745o6zAJsz3uqHiNpvw66iUfDIjvPTkb31ab4e0f79bac5f21063348326464a8.jpg`

Comment: What is `wxfile:`?

Comment: @Bergi a special type of temp file path within WeChat mini app.

Comment: So this code is not running in a standard browser?

Comment: @bergi yes, basically it is a browser without querySelector.

Comment: `querySelector` can be polyfilled so I don't see how that is relevant… What matters is whether the "browser" is running your code with special permissions (or even a special API) or not.

Comment: @bergi Sorry what I meant is the page is pre-render and does not return DOM event, which means no polyfill...you can give it a try here: https://mp.weixin.qq.com/debug/wxadoc/dev/devtools/download.html

Answer (score 1):

No, that is because `file://` is considered a different origin and for security reason blocked by the browser (imagine if you could arbitrarily point to say a password file on the user's disk..).

In the provided example in the question only the *string* holding the filename itself is baked into the blob (as shown when you decode it).

You will have to provide a mechanism such as `input` of type `file` to obtain a blob/file object from the user's system, or go via a (local) host (server) so a http(s) can be used via [`fetch()`](https://devdocs.io/dom/fetch_api/using_fetch) or [`XMLHttpRequest()`](https://devdocs.io/dom/xmlhttprequest).

Comment: Well, this is a Wechat mini app that I am making, where the querySelector is banned, that's why I didn't use `input[type=file] => reader.readAsDataURL()` method, `wx.chooseImage` is a replacement for input[type=file] except in this case it does not seem to support `Blob()`...

Comment: @AeroWang I am not familiar with the WeChat API, but you could perhaps try to use the localIds list but instead of setting it as source to an image load it via fetch or xhr as a blob (unless those are banned too..).

Comment: @AeroWang I may be mistaken and this being for something else, but in [this code](https://gist.github.com/xwpfullstack/60a119b8a9a6e24098f4#file-wechat-camera-L26) it seems as querySelector is allowed (?)

Comment: it has to be something else since mini app was introduced in 2017, and this is from 2 years ago. Probably some previous experiment.